# Copy a sequence of data from one table column to another table column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables A and B, table A has data like this:

| volumeA | dateA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 |
| 5 | 2022-01-02 |
| 8 | 2022-01-02 |

table B has data like this, with same number of rows as table A where dateB = 2022-01-01:

| volumeB | dateB |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 |

Now I'd like to copy volumeA from table A where date matches to table B (i.e. same date 2022-01-01), so table B will become this:

| volumeB | dateB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 |

How to do this in MySQL?

Comment: What if in table B there is another `0 2022-01-01` record, so 4 in total ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha forgot to mention in table B there is always exact same number of rows as table A where date = 2022-01-01

Comment: Can't be done with the columns provided. **Table rows do not have any inherent order**. Not even creation/insert order. The concept just _doesn't exist_ for relational databases. You need some way to distinguish and order specific rows in TableB in a deterministic way, and it's not possible with the data shown.

Comment: Does the tables have any auto_increment table or any column which will determine the order ?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Can I select the first 3 rows of table A and paste in the first 3 rows of table B?

Comment: @ErgestBasha no unfortunately not

Comment: @one-hand-octopus No, because **there's NO SUCH THING as "first"** for this. You **must** be able to define what you mean by "first" in terms of the data actually present in the table for this to work.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn how about `SELECT volumeB FROM tableB LIMIT 2, 1` or something like this?

Comment: @one-hand-octopus It won't work. The rows may have the same value, but they are still _different rows_, and without a deterministic ordering the database is free to give you **different results** from one moment to the next for the same query. This means, among other things, it could be possible to match the same row with each of the values from table A and overwrite it's contents, rather than setting three different rows.

Comment: The closest you can get is a windowing function like `row_number()` to project a unique id value onto each record. But this also requires you to nest it in a subquery to use it in the same statement, and I can't promise the database will maintain the relationship back to the original table through the subquery.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I've done this with CTE's to generate the row numbers, followed by an UPDATE that joins the original table to the CTE results. But that solution still needs a primary key in the table to be updated. I don't know of a solution for the OP's problem as they have described it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am missing something about your question, but if you could do what you describe then Table B would be in practice a copy of Table A, right?

Unless there are other columns in the two tables, that add some meaning to what you want to do (and possible provide a way to do what you want), I think that you are approaching this the wrong way.